# Issue with regular expression extracting all matches for a pattern in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to extract all the matches for a pattern in a string. The string is eg: "r[0] or c[0]" in tcl but the matched string is not what I expect.

I tried using regexp -all -inline to match all the substrings that match a pattern in the string.

```
%set p "r\[0\] and c\[0\]"
%r[0] and c[0]
% regexp ".\[\\d+\]" $p
%1
% set x [regexp -all -inline ".\[\\d+\]" $p]
%{[0} {[0}
```

Expected result is r[0] c[0] but result is [0 [0

Comment: Using braces, not double quotes, can reduce the number of backslashes you need. This is particularly key for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the type of result you want to get. As you have wrote it, you want to match every  *letter[digit]*  you find in a given string, being only one letter and one digit inside [].
You can use this regular expression to get it:

```
([a-zA-Z]\[\d\])
```

If you only want lower case letters, remove the A-Z.

From now on you could use https://www.regextester.com/ to check your regular expression before using it.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: I am trying this out in tcl shell and after trying out the above I get   % set p "r\[0\] and c\[0\]"
r[0] and c[0]
% set x [regexp -all -inline ([a-zA-Z]\[\d\]) $p]
invalid command name "a-zA-Z"

Comment: Is the regextester.com for perl?

Comment: This one worked - %set x [regexp -all -inline {([r|c]\[\d\])} $p]. But it returns {r[0]} {r[0]} {c[0]} {c[0]}, but that should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: @mickeyj, if you remove the capturing parentheses, your output will be more concise.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. That helped.